# Getting nil while performing UIAlertController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode7

I'm having a problem performing an UIAlertViewController in ViewController.

This is what I currently have

```
func displayLoginResult(viewModel: Login.PerformLogin.ViewModel) {
    endLoader(loader: loaderLogin)
    if let errorMessage = viewModel.displayedError {
        print(errorMessage.message)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter data in Text fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        router.navigateToGroupsScene()
    }
}
```

I've tried deleting DerivedData but nothing. I'm just considering the case that viewModel.displayedError is not nil (not the else case, just the if). I've seen if I comment this line:

`self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

all works but obviously any Dialog is displayed which is not what I want. I'm a bit frustrades due to I've never had a problem like this and Xcode provides me not much information.

Exception on Xcode:
[image]

Threads details:
[image]

Any further information you need, just let me know and I will provide you!

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your `self`? Is that `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to remove observer, add this code to your LoginViewController class:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, this doesn't solve my error, but now I can see from error comes, if I want to display the dialog with keyboard showing cause nil, but if I hide keyboard the dialog displays. Thank you, now I've just have to debug why this is happen! I've mark your answer as correct because it approximate as much to the solution :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using below code:

```
func displayLoginResult(viewModel: Login.PerformLogin.ViewModel) {
    endLoader(loader: loaderLogin)
    if let errorMessage = viewModel.displayedError {
        print(errorMessage.message)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter data in Text fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    }
    else {
        router.navigateToGroupsScene()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I've tried this and it doesn't works. Orest has give me from where error comes and now I've just have to find them. But the problem was about the keyboard observer. Thank you so much anyway!

Comment: thats nice  alex